# How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, images

How do I reduce the size of an image in Stack Overflow questions?

I have found large size images in many Stack Overflow questions. I feel the formatting does not look good. While moderating I have not found any option to reduce the image size.

How do I reduce a large image while moderating questions to improve Stack Overflow quality?

Comment: duplicate on MSE: [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/230282)

Answer (score 781, accepted):

### Add a character to the file name to specify a size

If the images are hosted on the Stack Exchange imgur.com account (which most are), you can add a [`h`, `l`, `m`, `t`, `b` or `s`](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) to the filename in the URL (before the extension) to get resized versions.

For that post, for example, you can use
 `https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCgl.jpg` instead of
 `https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCg.jpg` to get a more manageable size screenshot.

If needed, you can always link to the full-size screenshot too; transform:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCg.jpg
```

to

```
[![enter image description here][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCgl.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCg.jpg
```

and it'll link the reduced-size version to the full-size image.

I've gone ahead and used the medium (`m`) version for that post to reduce the size of the retina-resolution iPhone screenshots, linking each to the full-resolution version.

For completeness sake, the letters stand for:

```
s: small   square     90×90   (forced)
b: big     square     160×160 (forced)
t: small   thumbnail  160×160
m: medium  thumbnail  320×320
l: large   thumbnail  640×640
h: huge    thumbnail  1024×1024
```

The square options will scale the image (up as well as down) and crop to fit the size, thumbnails are only ever scaled down (smaller images are not scaled up) to fit with the square maximum dimensions.

**NOTE:** Resizing only preserves the first frame of an animated GIF image. If you need to resize an animation, use HTML markup instead (i.e. use `<img>`).

**WARNING:** Imgur seems to have consistency issues with generating the different sizes of images, where not all suffixes give you a resized image; and are instead served the original image. I don't know what causes this to happen or what a work-around might be.

### Add a `?s=X` query string to the URL for some square sizes

You can [add a query string to the URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post/296138#296138) to specify some specific sizes. The available sizes are dimensions that are the powers of two from 16 up to 512 (i.e. X can be 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 and 512).

Using this method will produce a square image. The image may be cropped and/or resized without preserving the image's aspect ratio.

Example (with link to full sized image):

```
[![enter image description here][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCg.jpg?s=256
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCg.jpg
```

### Use an `<img>` tag to specify exact dimensions

If you want to specify other sizes, you can use an `<img>` tag. The full image will be downloaded and scaled by the user's browser to fit the specified `width` and/or `height`.

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LCg.jpg" width="400" />
```

The `width` attribute tells the browser to constrain the size, the height is scaled along automatically.

When using an `<img>` tag, any attributes [must be specified in the following order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) or the image will not be displayed: `src`, `width`, `height`, `alt`, `title`. The values for the `width` and `height` attributes can be up to 999.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you please tell how to align it center

Comment: @SVM-RAJESH: you cannot; there are no alignment options.

Comment: @SVM-RAJESH: On [sites using MathJax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax), you can offset an image by `XX` pixels by inserting `$\hspace{XXpx}$` before it. On other sites like SO, though, the closest you can get is something like `&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ...`, and the offset that produces can vary widely depending on the fonts available to the viewer, as well as other settings, so you shouldn't really rely on it.

Comment: Is it possible that there has been changes for the image resizing? Currently neither **m**edium nor **l**arge do have any affect on an image of size 720x1280.

Comment: @Robert: imgur's implementation his having issues with different sizes at different times. No idea what causes this or what the work-arounds might be. Today it's the `t` size that's not working, for example.

Comment: Apparently Stackoverflow for Teams doesn't support all the same methods described... frustrating.

Comment: Please add the `src` `width` `height` `alt` `title` to the Markdown instructions page, i.e. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/editing-help . I spent hours going in circles wondering why my image was invisible before finding this.

Answer (score 70):

You can use the HTML `<img>` tag, instead of `[enter image description here][1]`. To do that, copy and paste this:

```
<img src="" width="" height="">
```

Then put the URL of the picture in the `src` attribute, and the desired width and height in their respective attributes. At the end, it looks like this:

```
<img src="www.com/.png" width="256" height="1337">
```

<sup><sub>Source: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/238586)</sub></sup>

Comment: Note that this only reduces the *display* size of the image; it does nothing to reduce the time or bandwidth required to load it.

Comment: On the plus side, that bandwidth is not necessarily wasted if the image is shrunk by ~200%: retina displays will show the image non-blurry if you inserted a large one and specified a smaller width or height in the `img` tag. This seems to be the only way of inserting retina-friendly images on SO, not that it matters that much for this type of content.