# How can I put images side by side in a Stack Overflow question?

Tags: support, markdown, images

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808544/float-layout-in-interface-builder-in-ios) question, and down in my question there is two big image. Is it a way to put them / align them side by side, to take less vertical space when visitors reading it?

### Example

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The key is to not put a line break between them.

Once you add a line feed between them, they are on two separate lines and rendered accordingly.

Note the gap between the images.  If you don't want that, remove the space.

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

The text of the answer is:

```
The key is to not give them any room between them.

Once you add a line feed between them, they are on two separate lines and rendered accordingly.

Note the gap between the images.  If you don't want that, remove the space.

![image 1][2] ![image 2][3]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL6j1.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UTOh.png
```

Comment: There doesn't need to be absolutely *no* space between them, just not the blank line. Removing the extra line-break (while still leaving them on separate lines) would also work.

Comment: If the images are large, they won't come side by side in this method. In that case you'd have to [append an 'm' to the image url](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 33):

Next time around you can use basic [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) like so:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKgXQ.jpg" width="250">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT1ZY.jpg" width="400">
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice selection of pics :P

Comment: @Sam Just a couple of my wife's sculptures. The one on the left is "The Happy Hunter" and the other one is "The Vomit Platter". She used the Vomit Platter to serve sushi when it was displayed at her school's art show.

Comment: thank you for the concise diagrams. they are helpful in identifying the underlying problem.

Comment: @Sam Personally, I would've gone with some [place kittens](http://placekitten.com). Irresistible!

Comment: worked for me. thanks. the ![description][number] method does not work for me. :(

Answer (score 10):

If your images are too large, you can resize them by altering the filename to access one of the six different "thumbnail" options [detailed here](http://api.imgur.com/models/image)

For example, change the filename from

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3NKB.jpg

to

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3NKBh.jpg

and you can fit two Coral memes side by side.

[image] [image]

Comment: Such a dark meme

Comment: His name is Carl.

Comment: Pshh, use the [real picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsoUr.jpg)!

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, I figured it out.. I can edit / put together the two images .. for example, with [Photoshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop).

**This was my first idea** that came in my mind, but now I see **there are more elegant solutions**. **I recommend to use MichaelT solution**.

[image]

Comment: Well, using a graphics editor, you certainly get more flexibility... and into more trouble. :)

Comment: Using a graphic editor can "solve" many formatting issues, but it's not what usually people understand under "formatting" ;)

Comment: agree, this is why I accepted MichaelT's solution, that is more elegant :-)

Comment: Not sure why people are -1 this, other than "why the hell didn't he just do that in the first place?"  But that's what I would have done initially.  +1