# Why not have stack overflow a lightbox for the images?

Tags: feature-request

Why not have a lightbox on images?

I saw this post for increased image size:
[How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow)

But I think a lightbox is a better solution for see what is exactly on the image, because the normal size is useless, if you would like to show text or something smaller.
If you embed the big image, this takes too much time for others, when the page loads.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english, I realy I tried to ask a good question

Comment: I don't mind this request, but images should almost *never* be conveying text here, especially code. Tried to fix up your grammar/spelling for you.

Comment: Sometimes need it.
For example in super user:
http://superuser.com/questions/853516/how-can-i-add-link-class-for-microsoft-office-word-2013-blog-post
In this context, I half see the link inside the text.

Comment: Ugh, that person should have just taken a better screenshot. *Most* of the time that would solve the issue entirely.

Comment: Anyway, i think the best solution for images,optimalized page loads the lightbox.
Actualy, this plugin is close enough for anything:
http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview/documentation/usage

Comment: Like I said, I don't have a problem with adding the link. It can only help, no harm, no foul. Just saying I don't think that its a super *important* change.

Comment: Half true.
Now we soon on 2015 and every page is use lightbox for images.
I mean this is good and modern stie, this feature is only one is missed.

Comment: Look, I'm not going to argue with you about web UX design. Just realize that images are *fairly rare* on Stack Overflow, and only a small percentage of those would benefit from the feature. If this gets implemented, great! If not, I honestly won't care.

Comment: Any feature that encourages SO questioners to use screenshots should be extinguished with fire.  Such questions are useless, Google cannot easily index them.

Comment: The vast majority of images I encounter in questions are put there because the poster is too lazy to properly include text or describe the problem. Images should be a *last resort*, and only used for questions where there's no other way to demonstrate or describe the problem. I agree with @Hans - anything than encourages posting of images should be immediately lit with a torch.

Comment: I came here to ask the same thing, and I had [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614135/why-does-delphi-xe7-change-png-image-on-every-fmx-form-save) as an example. I disagree with Hand and Ken. If someone asks a bad question because if code in images instead of question, then you should just downvote or close the question. You shouldn't avoid having certain features because they *may be* abused, especially since I think people who post such questions haven't even checked whether there is a lightbox or not.

Comment: That said, as long as it is not implemented, there is at least an easy work-around (in Chrome at least). You can just open the image in a new or existing tab by dragging it to the tab bar.