# Why is uploading Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) not supported?

Tags: feature-request, images

I prefer to add images to my questions or answers - often from different sources. Most of time the offered quality of the images is really bad so I'm tempted to redraw them. I find the svg format often very suitable due to the fact that one can zoom in and out. However, it seems SO does not support uploading this kind of image format. Why is that?

Comment: Cross site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads

Comment: @Andy thanks, indeed I checked only SO.meta totally forgetting about SE.meta

Comment: see also comments under https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395027/997587 (concerning imgur support ending)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quoting from a post on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92677/186281):

> Stack Exchange supports image uploading by using an external service (imgur) which does not support vector images.

Imgur does not support the SVG format. They have an open [feature request](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/23630-svg-support/) for such support.

---

If your SVG image is hosted elsewhere, you can embed it in the post using HTML:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"/>
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: thx that makes sense up to the point where I want to use an image link which is also not supported. E.g. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg

Comment: You can utilize an image link. I've provided an example in my post

Comment: True, forgot about the HTML embed options. Do you know if it's also possible to scale those linked images like explained [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow/253405#253405).

Comment: You should be able to use the `height` and `width` attributes to scale it. The automatic scaling provided by Imgur isn't available, because your SVG won't be hosted there as an SVG file.

Comment: You can also use `![Alt text](http://www.example.com/path/to/file.svg)`

Comment: Just make sure the SVG [is not hosted by Facebook](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384864/stack-overflow-lets-facebook-track-us-across-their-sites?cb=1) :).

Comment: While this answer is useful it's arguable that S.O.'s goals would suggest that they'd be better served by switching to a service that supports SVG and maybe even one that includes an inline or modal SVG editor. Just like you can click to insert a snippet i'd draw way more helpful diagrams if I could click "insert diagram" and have a simple diagram editor popup. As it is I often rely on ascii art which is way more painful to enter.

Answer (score 7):

I have following SVG file on my PC

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
    
      <title>SVG 3 Circles Intersection </title>
    
        <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
                fill="none"
                />
        <text x="110" y="110" 
              text-anchor="middle"
              stroke="red"
              stroke-width="1px"
              > Label
        </text>
        <circle cx="240" cy="110" r="100" 
                stroke="blue" 
                stroke-width="3"
                fill="none"
                />
        <text x="240" y="110" 
              text-anchor="middle" 
              stroke="blue" 
              stroke-width="1px"
              > Ticket
        </text>
        <circle cx="170" cy="240" r="100" 
                stroke="green" 
                stroke-width="3" 
                fill="none"
                />
        <text x="170" y="240" 
              text-anchor="middle" 
              stroke="green" 
              stroke-width="1px"
              > Vecto
        </text>
    </svg>
```

I have uploaded this image to [https://svgur.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20221226070030/http://svgur.com/)

After upload was terminated, I have obtained following URL:

```
https://svgshare.com/i/H7d.svg
```

I had to then **MANUALLY** (without using IMAGE icon) add the following `<img>` HTML tag

```
<img src="https://svgshare.com/i/H7d.svg"/>
```

and the result is just below

[image]
<sub>Editor's Note: svgur.com and svgshare.com do not appear to be working; links and resources have been replaced with webarchive links where possible, but may not function as desired.</sub>

For user with some doubt, it is possible to see what I have done in editing following answer [on Stack Overflow inserting SVG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128491/svg-center-text-in-circle/52719480#52719480)

The SVG file must contain `<?xml?>` element. At begin, I have simply created a SVG file that begins directly with `<svg>` tag and nothing worked!

At first, I tried to insert an image using IMAGE icon of Edit Toolbar. I paste URL of my SVG file but Stack Overflow don't accept this method. The `<img>` tag must be added manually.

I hope that this answer can help other users.

REMARK: svgshare is NOT SAFE

Images on SVGSHARE disappears after some times.

Now, I use a public personnal repositories on GITHUB !

[image]

This image is on //github.com/schlebe/SVG-Images/blob/main/Cercles.Selection.svg

Comment: FWIW, the team involved in the upcoming migration from imgur to the new image hosting solution are aware that some of us would like SVG. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395027/334566