# Badges in the "Vote Up" privilege page in the help center are images

Tags: feature-request, design, help-center, images

At the bottom of the [Privileges > Vote Up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) page on the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), there is a list of badges one can get through voting:

> [image: Voting]

They look blurry because they are images in the HTML, e.g. the [Supporter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter) badge uses this image

[image: Supporter].

with the following HTML:

```html
<p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/km2qC.png" alt="Supporter"><br>First upvote.</p>
```

---

On the [Help Center > Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page on the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) however, the badges are beautfully rendered with HTML and CSS:

```html
<a href="/help/badges/6/supporter" title="bronze badge: First up vote" class="badge"><span class="badge3"></span>&nbsp;Supporter</a>
```

Most of the time this wouldn't be noticable, but it is a pain for those who might have their browser in large fonts, or visit the site through a mobile browser and regularly have to zoom in to see parts of the page.

At the maximum zoom level in Firefox (300%), this is how the two compare:

[image]
[image]

I don't think I need to say which is the horrible image and which is lovely HTML and CSS.

This is compounded by the fact that the font used and the style for the `Span` in the image isn't the same as the font in the HTML - presumably this was changed at some point but the images weren't updated:

**Image** → [image: Supporter image]
 vs. [image: Supporter from HTML and CSS] ← **HTML and CSS**

---

This inconsistency has been around at least as far back as the first mirrors of the pages on web.archive.org from 2013: [the Badges page, on 2013-06-20](http://web.archive.org/web/20130620140848/https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) used HTML and CSS; [the Privileges > Vote Up page, on 2013-07-01](http://web.archive.org/web/20130701060726/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) used images.

---

The [Vote Up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) page should be amended to address this issue.

Comment: TIL StackOverflow is not 508 compliant

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I deliberately didn't mention compliance to various standards, etc. because I (possibly naïvely) thought having alt-text for the image would be enough. Is that not the case?

Comment: I believe that alt text is acceptable under 508 compliance

Comment: We could maybe update the images to be better quality, but that's all we're able to do. Those articles are just posts stored in the database and get rendered with the same engine that renders any other post on the site. It's not possible to include actual badge HTML on that page.

Comment: Could the images be changed to use SVG instead?

Comment: @Aaroninus - that was my thought too, but when I tried to add an SVG file through ingur, it said: "Failed to upload; not a valid image (jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp)". When I tried a .svg which existed already, it just failed to show it.

Comment: @animuson - I had hoped it would be possible since it was done in the Badges page, but I fully accept that if you're telling me it can't be done, it can't be done.

Comment: Nearly four years later I've become aware that SVG [can be embedded in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299314/1364007) - just not using the image uploader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer an issue because the badges are referred to by text only now:

[image]