# Support svg images for company images in developer story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, images

At the moment, when editing/adding a company position to your developer story and trying to upload a SVG company logo using their "link from the web" or uploading manually, it will results in the following error:

> The format is not supported

This is a shame as many companies are going to implement SVG images for their logo's to make them look better on the high resolution displays.

At the moment, according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) 97.17 % of all browsers support svg already, therefore I propose that the developer story should accept SVG files as company logo's

---

This is not really a duplicate of [Why is uploading Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) not supported?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299313/why-is-uploading-scalable-vector-graphics-svg-not-supported), because with normal posts you can just use the image markdorn syntax manually, and that supports SVG properly, companies on developer story are "uploader" only, its answers do not apply in this situation

Comment: @WGx the duplicate is about Stack Overflow proper, though. This one is about the developer story.

Comment: Developer Story uses the same underlying Image Provider - if Imgur adds support for SVG, Stack Overflow and Developer Story will support it.