# Bug in resized thumbnail imgur image with alpha channel

Tags: bug

I recently found out [that I can include images with various sizes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow/253405#253405), and I've been using the feature happily ever since. Today I ran into a situation where the resized (resampled?) versions of a png image are distorted.

Original:

[image: original size, fine]

---

Resized to ["square"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow/253405#253405) sizes (`b`,`s`):

[image: b size, OK]
[image: s size, OK]

---

Resized to ["thumbnail"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow/253405#253405) sizes (`h`,`l`,`m`,`t`):

[image: h size, oh the horror]
[image: l size]
[image: m size]
[image: t size]

Is the resizing/resampling done by SO, or by imgur? In other words, who should fix this bug? And does anyone know what kinds of images could be affected?

### Update:

@brasofilo kindly pointed me to their [similar question on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199889/185667). In the mean time I realized what's wrong with the image, and this makes me think that the two problems might not be related.

The image in question has an alpha channel rather than having a background colour:

[image: caught alpha-handed]

It seems straighforward to assume that the "thumbnail" versions are messed up due to the alpha channel present in the image.

My question remains: who should fix this bug?

Comment: I asked the same last year at big meta: [Imgur medium images with too much compression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199889/185667)

Comment: @brasofilo aah, thanks, I looked around meta.SO but forgot to check SE. Although this case seems a bit more severe than what's demonstrated in yours.

Comment: @brasofilo I realized that an alpha channel is causing the trouble, which suggests that your and my problems might not be related. What do you think?