# Images are blurry when reducing the size

Tags: support, images, imgur

I followed [this Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow) to reduce my image size via the [`h, l, m, t, b, s`](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) approach and it looked blurry. I then tried `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/someimage.jpg" width="400" />` approach and it was crisper.  Is this behavior expected?

**Reduced via shorthand**

[image: Reduced via shorthand]

**Reduced via HTML**

[image]

**Manual resize via paint.net**

[image: Manual resize via Paint.NET]

Comment: Surely that's an Imgur issue, not a SE issue? When you set the width in the HTML your browser's doing the resizing and rendering; when you add the size suffix it's Imgur resizing it.

Comment: That is how image resizing works.  You are missing the crusty NY cop that barks "enhance!" at the crime lab technician.

Comment: http://www.criticalcommons.org/Members/ironman28/clips/bladeRunner3DphotoH264.mov/view

Comment: Are you on an iPhone, Retina MacBook Pro or some other high density display?

Comment: @BrianNickel 22" 1920 x 1080 Asus monitor

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  I got really confused when I [opened this question on my iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHWCB.png).  I don't know exactly what Imgur is doing, and if the trade-off is text quality, but their scaled version is only 10KB and yours is 24KB.  Gotta agree with Stijn's answer though.

Comment: Very useful tip about resizing with html. In the past I have often added white or transparent space to my images to make them 1000 pixels wide. That way they still appeared sharp and at a reasonable size.

Comment: I don't know much about web tech. Can't Stack Exchange do something like the html effect above without making the users paste in the html code?

Answer (score 19):

When using `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/someimage.jpg" width="400" />`, the original image is downloaded by the browser, then it is [scaled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) by the browser with a certain algorithm.

When using the Imgur thumbnail approach, an already scaled image is downloaded by the browser. Imgur apparently uses an algorithm that results in significantly lower quality, which is especially visible in screenshots of text.
Presumably this is intentional on Imgur's part (they *are* called thumbnails), but you could contact their support team to verify this. Regardless, there's no problem on Stack Overflow's part.

Comment: Presumably the "lower quality" is intentional, but not necessarily the "especially text" part. It's just that Imgur is probably optimized for photos since that's what most of their content used to be (before memes became popular, at least)