# Images cannot be resized in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, images

When posting images on Stack Overflow and other sites in the network, we can choose between the original image and [a number of different sizes by adding `l` or `m` or `s` before `.png`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow)

However, on Stack Overflow for Teams, this does not seem to work.

[image: Screen shot of ... screen shot!]

Adding a resizing suffix of any kind creates a broken image link:

[image: Screen shot of broken screen shot]

Comment: That's because they're not hosted on imgur, and the resize thing is an imgur feature. So this is more a [feature-request] than a [bug].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Floern's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364368/images-cannot-be-resized-in-stack-overflow-for-teams#comment563694_364368) is correct about why single-letter URL size-changing options that work on our public sites aren't available on Teams – Teams does not use Imgur.

To specify dimensions on Teams, use HTML.

For example:

```
<img src="https://pukurbd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/1-1.png" width="100" height="100">
```

Our restrictions on using HTML are very strict. You may only use the src, width, height, alt, and title attributes on an `<img>`, and they must appear in that order. Any other order will be invalid.

Comment: Prior to your answer and edit of the question, this was a [meta-tag:feature-request]. Does your response here, along with editing the question, indicate that the actual response to the [meta-tag:feature-request] is "[meta-tag:status-declined], but you can use HTML to do that"? I'm not saying that's a bad thing. I'm just trying to be sure there's clarity as to what's going on. From the point of view of the future, changing this to a [meta-tag:support] question effectively means that someone else could post a new, essentially identical, [meta-tag:feature-request] if they still want the feature.

Comment: It was decided to remove the feature-request tab because there's no definitive decision on whether or not single-letter URL size-changing options will get worked on. It may be declined, or it may be deferred, but right now, it's up in the air. Rather than put the incorrect status after responding, we decided to turn it into a support question.