# Is image sizing broken?

Tags: support, images

I just tried to [reduce image size](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow) on for the following question, but the images are still huge

[Read the `Power Saving Modes` settings on the MIUI devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779660/read-the-power-saving-modes-settings-on-the-miui-devices)

I tried both `m` and `t` sized images. Is this broken on this end, or by imgur?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly