# How do I size an image on Stack Overflow without the clipping?

Tags: support

In [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804075/main-and-visibly-apparent-difference-between-n-tier-and-clean-architecture) I sized an image linked to as suggested by [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow/253405#253405).

It works, but the right part of the image is being cut off. It's not a deal-breaker, but the nit-pick I am, I wonder why and how to get rid of this phenomenon.

Comment: [Markdown is extremely limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14747656/6296561), and the imgur thumb sizes break the image in several ways. Converting it to an img tag with a specified width resizes it, while keeping the height automatic. Also, the answer you linked explicitly states `Using this method will produce a square image. The image may be cropped and/or resized without preserving the image's aspect ratio.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?s=256` parameter to the image URL sets the size to 256x256 pixels, but the actual dimension is 627x591. So you're basically telling a non-square image to fit in a square box and it gets cropped. You could simply remove the query parameter from the link and instead just set the width [like this](https://superuser.com/a/1238701/461722).

Comment: Oh, cool. I saw that too in the answer but I (mistakenly) assumed that I have to create a copy of the image locally on my drive, shrink it and rename it. You are saying that I can add "s" to any image's name and SO is bright enough to smallify it form me, correct?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana as long as you want it to have the same width and height, yes. But generally you'll only want to do that with images that are already perfectly square or you'll get the result you saw with cropping. If you want to shrink an image that isn't square it's better to just set the width and let the browser figure out the correct height. I see someone edited your original question to do just that.